# Automating the emailing of an invoice AND one or more files

Tags: gratis, online-payment

I usually create invoices by an `invoice-creator-software` and emails an invoice to a customer alongside another document containing payment instructions.

I desire to automate the emailing of an invoice AND one or more file/s instead doing the two "sets" of these actions manually each time anew.

Some `invoice-creator-software` give an option to email an invoice directly from the software (most likely by sending it from the software company's server) but I have never came across a software which allows to *automatically* include any other file.

I ask for a recommendation for such software with these characteristics:

- FOSS
- Windows and Linux oriented
- The email could be sent from the software developer's servers as one PDF containing the invoice and under it the second file with payment instructions; such as bank account details (and possible ways to do the bank transfer), or some payment-software account details.

Do you have a recommendation for a software automating the emailing of an invoice AND one or more files?